# Using integer in data as condition on number of rows in table

Tags: sql, count, distinct, db2-zos

This is a representation of my table T1:

```
acc_id|acc_holders|bal_1|bal_2
00001|002|50|100
00001|002|50|100
00002|001|100|100
00003|003|50|100
00003|003|50|100
```

`acc_holders` indicates the number of account holders. The `bal_1` figure represents the account balance split evenly between the holders. `Bal_2` represents the overall account balance.

The problem is that in some rows (e.g. for `acc_id` 00003), the `acc_holders` value does not match the number of times that account appears (00003 should appear 3 times).

I'd like to select these anomalies using something like:

```
SELECT acc_id from t1
WHERE acc_holders <> count(distinct acc_id)
```

This throws error "misuse of aggregate function count()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea:

```
select acc_id
from t1
group by acc_id, acc_holders
having count(*) <> acc_holders;
```

Or, you might want:

```
select acc_id
from t1
group by acc_id, acc_holders
having count(*) <> min(acc_holders) or
       min(acc_holders) <> max(acc_holders);
```

You have two potential problems.  One is that `acc_holders` might not represent the number of account rows.  The second is that `acc_holders` might vary among rows for a given account.  This latter version gets both these situations.

Comment: pretty sure that the second scenario doesn't exist, but worth trying to catch in any case